# Fingerprint reader doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, hp, fingerprint-reader

Fingerprint GUI does not support my Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `fprint` from the `fprintd` package.  That worked on my Upek fingerprint sensor.  But you will still need to type in a password to decrypt anything in your keyring, for use in things like email, so the fingerprint sensor may not be as useful as you'd like.